# Stop Playing Default Android Ringtone and play user defined ringtone during Incoming calls

Tags: android, ringtone

I am trying to play a ringtone which I save for my contacts like described below

```
        Mringtone = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);

        Mringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL);
        Mringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE,
                "Select RingTone");
        Mringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI,
                (Uri) Uri.parse(SelectedRingTone));
        this.startActivityForResult(Mringtone, 0);
```

And on Activity result I am getting the ringtone URI and saving it to my Table

```
CustomRingToneUri = data.getParcelableExtra(mRingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

            if (CustomRingToneUri != null) {

                int updateRes=            getContentResolver().update(URI_MY_TABLE,contactRingTone(CustomRingToneUri.toString()),
                        "_id = " + "\"" + receivedExtra + "\"", null);
}
```

So it is updating properly as expected, and I am using PhoneStateListener to receive Incoming call, I am trying to play the ringtone from the URI I receive from my Table as shown Below

```
Uri ConvertedToUri;

        ConvertedToUri = Uri.parse(IncomingNumberRingtonePath);
        ringTone=ringToneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ConvertedToUri);
        if (ringTone.isPlaying())
            ringTone.stop();
        ringTone.play();
```

If I get a incoming call I am getting played both default and save ringtone played at the same time. I tried using **stopPreviousRingTone** too. it is not helping me. Kindly provide me some feasible ways

Thanks
Venkatraman